# How to make an infinite rotation with Angular animations?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-animations

I need a div to rotate infinite.
So, I created this animation:

```
animations: [
    trigger('rotate', [
        transition(':enter', [style({transform: 'rotate(-360deg)'}), animate('2000ms')])
    ])
]
```

It rotates, but stoppes after 2 sec. That's logic. But how can I make the rotation being infinite?

Comment: afaik, there is no functionality to infinite loop animations, you may get this result by using the callbacks, or if its just a "div" animation, you can use the old good keyframes through css.

Comment: @dAxx_ is right : why would you bother with Angular animations when it's so simple to make a div instead ?

Comment: Okay, then I have to use the old way ;)
I need to do some more animations and I didn't want to mix it up. And the old way is a chunk of code, I think.
Thank you for your help, @dAxx_ and @trichetriche!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `animation-iteration-count` property is not supported in Angular 6. There is an open GitHub issue requesting support for it.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20621

You can define *infinite* animations easily in CSS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count

A person created a demo of how to do infinite animations with Angular using callbacks.

https://angular-animations-demo.firebaseapp.com/loop-demo